# Catch exception in contact form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm going to create form contact in asp.net mvc 4. I have yet form in html and code in controller.  And his looks like:

```
       [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Kontakt(KontaktModel k)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress(k.Mail.ToString());
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                msg.To.Add("myemail@gmail.com");
                msg.Subject = k.Temat.ToString();
                msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                sb.Append("Nick / Imię i nazwisko: " + k.Name);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append("Typ problemu: " + k.TypProblemu);
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append("Treść:");
                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                sb.Append(k.Tresc);
                msg.Body = sb.ToString();
                smtp.Send(msg);
                msg.Dispose();
                return View("SUCCESS");
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }


}
```

But when I clicked to button app return Error.cshtml. I have a question, how I can know how exception catched? I don't know why it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer should be to get  the Exception Message and put  inside a ViewBag.Message and show it in the Error.cshtml view.

## Error:

@ViewBag.Message

But is good to know  little more about Exception and Exception Handling. If you only declare a **try catch** and a exception happen it will go inside  the catch is the same if you do **try catch(Exception)** if you want to know more detail about the exception is happening you can declare a variable, example :

```
try{
   ///code
 }catch(Exception e){}
```

and then you can watch inside the variable for more detail.

The good practice is to know what type of exception you can receive and handle, here is a link that have a good explanation [Exception and Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx)

Example:

```
try
{
 //code
}
catch(Exception c)
{
  ViewBag.Message = c.Message
  return View("ERROR");
}
```